# select record from filtered results in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function which gives me ordered rows (the function already order by the results):

By doing : `select * from func1(ID)`

Example A:

```
rownum  date qty
1       1.1.10  -5
2       1.10.10  6
3       2.10.10  6
4       5.10.10  -2
5       6.10.10  -8
```

Example B:

```
rownum  date qty
1       1.1.10  -7
2       1.10.10  6
```

Note: `rownum` is a column i calculate manually in my function. It's order is exact to my needs. So it's ok to be based on that.

I want to write a query which pass over the rows from **bottom to top** (highest `rownum` till lowest `rownum`) and return the `date` of the first encountered row that has negative `qty`

For example A the returned value is `6.10.10` (rownum 5 is the first row with negative value of qty)
for example B `1.1.10` (rownum 2 is the first row with negative value of qty)

How can I do that?

Comment: for example B I think you mean `rownum 1 is the first row `

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it isn't there are many columns I showed only the necessary data... the order of rows is according to my needs and you can base your answer by assuming that rownum is in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rownum DESC) as rn
   FROM func1(ID)
   WHERE qty < 0
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that table-valued functions in Postgres guarantee the ordering of the results.  You will need to use an `order by` or some other mechanism.

If you want the most recent date with a negative value:

```
select max(date)
from func1(ID) t
where qty < 0;
```

If you have another ordering in mind:

```
select date
from func1(ID) t
where qty < 0
order by rownum desc --  your order by conditions here, but inverted
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This will allow you to fetch other values from the row, if you like.

Comment: But your first query is perfect if rownum is based on date.

Comment: what is the differece between `fetch first 1 row only;` and `limit 1` ??

Comment: The rownum  is calculated by my function it isn't a calculated randomly.. their order is exact and correct to my needs

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The former is ANSI standard SQL.  The latter is specific to particular databases.